# change tables captions from title case to sentence case automatically?

Tags: tables

I am using Thesis.cls to write my PhD thesis. After writing all tables captions in title case, I discovered that it is required that they be written in sentence case. Is there a way to change the case in all thesis tables automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There are lots and lots of Latex document classes called `Thesis` out on the Internet. Which one of these might you be using?

Comment: Do the arguments of the various `\caption` statements contain word -- such as the names of countries and cities, and persons' surnames -- that should NOT be changed to lowercase even if sentence style is to be used?

Comment: The file I am using has the following header.. and no I don't have words that should not be turned to lower case in my titles::                                             
    %% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk